How to calculate conditional counts and sums?
I want to do something similar of COUNTIFS and SUMIFS in R using data.table package.
Here is my data.
library(data.table)
treesData<-as.data.table(trees)
bins<-seq(63, length.out = 10, by = 3);
aggtable <- data.table(bin1 = bins[-length(bins)], bin2 = bins[-1])

This is what I want to achieve:
Count is countifs on height if it is in the interval
and Girth.total is sum on girth.


An alternative is to use a non-equi join, and leverage .EACHI:
treesData[aggtable,on=.(Height>=bin1, Height<bin2),.(ct = .N, Girth = sum(Girth)),.EACHI]

Output:
   Height Height    ct Girth
    <num>  <num> <int> <num>
1:     63     66     3  31.2
2:     66     69     1  11.0
3:     69     72     3  33.7
4:     72     75     4  53.9
5:     75     78     6  73.3
6:     78     81     7 104.5
7:     81     84     4  56.3
8:     84     87     2  26.2
9:     87     90     1  20.6

Note that non-equi join's in data.table can be confusing with regards to naming. A more complete option could be:
aggtable = treesData[aggtable,on=.(Height>=bin1, Height<bin2),.(ct = .N, Girth = sum(Girth)),.EACHI]
setnames(aggtable, new=c("Bin1", "Bin2", "Count", "Girth.sum"))


Thanks. Is this what you would suggest if I want to do further
aggtable[,Girth.sum:= treesData[aggtable,on=.(Height>=bin1, Height<bin2),.(Count= .N, Girth.sum = sum(Girth)),.EACHI]$Girth.sum];```
This I am doing to 1) create appropriate column in the `aggtable` and 2) to not display the output in console.

This kind of approach is more general, and gives rise to a procedure that has better statistical performance: using moving windows (overlapping bins).

@Mohit, actually I would not recommend that, because you are doing the join twice, once for each variable. See my update

Suggest using interval notation to make it clear which endpoints are included and excluded.
treesData[, bin := cut(Height, bins, right = FALSE)][,
  .(count = .N, tot = sum(Girth)), keyby = bin]

giving
Key: <bin>
       bin count   tot
    <fctr> <int> <num>
1: [63,66)     3  31.2
2: [66,69)     1  11.0
3: [69,72)     3  33.7
4: [72,75)     4  53.9
5: [75,78)     6  73.3
6: [78,81)     7 104.5
7: [81,84)     4  56.3
8: [84,87)     2  26.2
9: [87,90]     1  20.6

Note
Inputs
library(data.table)

treesData<-as.data.table(trees)
bins<-seq(63, length.out = 10, by = 3)


A bit simpler, group on the fly: treesData[, .(count = .N, tot = sum(Girth)), keyby = .(bin = cut(Height, bins, right = FALSE)) ]

Thanks, please may I request just 2 more improvements, 1) the 2 columns count and tot on the right of the data.table aggtable and 2) when running this code do not display the output in console.

If treeData[...][...] is the above solution then change that to
DT <- treeData[...][...][, cbind(aggtable, .SD)]

You can use
cond <- expression(treesData$Height %between% .(bin1, bin2 - 1))

aggtable[, c("Count", "Girth.Total") := list(
  sum(eval(cond)),
  sum(treesData$Girth[eval(cond)])), by = .I]

#> aggtable
#    bin1  bin2 Count Girth.Total
#   <num> <num> <int>       <num>
#1:    63    66     3        31.2
#2:    66    69     1        11.0
#3:    69    72     3        33.7
#4:    72    75     4        53.9
#5:    75    78     6        73.3
#6:    78    81     7       104.5
#7:    81    84     4        56.3
#8:    84    87     2        26.2
#9:    87    90     1        20.6


somewhat I think the code can be built  in the data.table square brackets itself without even using eval and expression.
